# When there is an increase in temperature, how is the pH of the ocean affected? (Question is related to ocean acidification)

Tags: equilibrium, ph, temperature, geochemistry

This is my current understanding:
Ocean acidification is the result of atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$  dissolving in the ocean's water. When this occurs the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the ocean decreases (from the increase in $\ce{H3O+}$ ions produced from the dissociation of $\ce{H2CO3}$). 
When there is an increase in temperature, the solubility of carbon dioxide decreases which results in a lower concentration of carbonic acid (the formation of carbonic acid is from the reaction of $\ce{CO2}$ with $\ce{H2O}$ which is exothermic, so the reverse reaction is favoured). 
So since the concentration of carbonic acid is lower, the concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ ions decreases (lower concentration of acid dissociates in the water). 
Therefore, the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the ocean increases as there are fewer $\ce{H3O+}$ ions present in the water.

Is my understanding correct, or have I made a mistake in my explanation?
If you can help me out I would be very grateful :)

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/15939/30836

Answer (score 2):

You have to compare the size of these counteracting effects.

The temperature increase **slightly decreases** the acidification caused by increased carbon dioxide partial pressure.

The shift of reaction constant is minimal.

From the [Wikipedia carbon dioxide data page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_%28data_page%29?wprov=sfla1), Water solubility section, we can see for temperature  15 resp 17 $^\circ$C V/V solubility 1.019 resp. 0.956. That is 6.2% lower solubility.

Increased partial $\ce{CO2}$ pressure from 0.03 to 0.04% gives 33%, what is significantly more than by 6.2% decreased solubility.

Aside of that, higher $\ce{CO2}$ concentration and lower sea water $\mathrm{pH}$ are already observed.

This is directly affecting carbonate related equilibriums, particularly in context of forming of mollusk shells.

Some mollusks are already observed  having troubles in forming aragonite - the more soluble form of calcium carbonate.

Comment: @Night Writer Well, in my understanding, in given context, the raise of temperature, increase of CO2 And sea acidification cannot be separated.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see my mistake!